# Creating a list of lists of a file analysis tool

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, glob

I have a lot of files that need to be processed for a data analysis, but first I need to separate them in groups.
File name goes like this : Name_'Frequency'Hz_'Number'.csv
I need to make a list of every 'Frequency' separated and have their 'Number' in order.
I'm using the glob function to separate most of the 'Number'.

I'm using this to import multiple files as pandas dataframe for further analysis.

Based on what I tried I mostly got:

```py
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I've been coding for 2 weeks now and I have no idea how to fix this issue.
Thank you all.
The issue:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFlg5.png]

For my code :

```py
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    
general_filename = 'Name_'
    
frequency_list = 10, 15, 25, 30, 100, 500
    
obj = {}
    
for frequency in frequency_list:
        obj[files,frequency] = glob.glob(file_path + '/' + general_filename + frequency + 'Hz_*.csv')
    
    print(obj)
```

Comment: convert integer value to string.. str(frequency)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, because `frequency` is int, you cannot concatenate with str.

But, you can;

```py
for frequency in frequency_list:
    obj[f"files_{frequency}"] = glob.glob(file_path + '/' + general_filename + str(frequency) + 'Hz_*.csv')
```

or, I prefer:

```py
for frequency in frequency_list:
    obj[f"files_{frequency}"] = glob.glob(f'{file_path}/{general_filename}{frequency}Hz_*.csv')
```

Comment: I get why you would need to use str( function but now python gives another error message. TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: may be. you should define frequency_list  as frequency_list = [10, 15, 25, 30, 100, 500] (use brackets :))

Answer (score 0):

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askdirectory()


general_filename = 'Name_'

frequency_list = [10, 15, 25, 30, 100, 500]

obj = {}

for frequency in frequency_list:
    obj[files+str(frequency)] = glob.glob(file_path + '/' + general_filename + str(frequency) + 'Hz_*.csv')

print(obj)
```

Just use the `str()` method to convert an integer to string and concatenate with other strings.

Comment: I get why you would need to use str( function but now python gives another error message.  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Thank you but it worked with the other answer `obj[f"files_{frequency}"]`